# sending mail with smtp relay and yandex.mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, yandex

I'm trying to send mail to a new users of a certain website and for now it goes to a spam folder.

This is what I do

```
private function sendMail($code, $mail)
{
    $link = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/?regcontinue='.$code;

    $to = $mail;
    $subject = "Registration on our amazing website";

    $message = ' 
            <html> 
                <head> 
                    <title>Registration on our amazing website</title> 
                </head> 
                <body> 
                    <p>Please, follow this link:</p>
                    <p><a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></p>
                </body> 
            </html>';

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Registration bot<bot@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

`SERVER_NAME` contains a hostname of a backend.

To avoid mail go to spam folder I chose to use Yandex.Mail for a domain https://domain.yandex.com/domains_add/

DNS record filled.

I just can't figure out how to arrange this middleware so mail could go through yandex.mail domain. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using the low lever `mail()`-function, you can use one of the tried and tested mail libraries such as PHPMailer, Swift Mailer or similar. Not only do they have a way more verbose API, but they don't require you to configure anything on server and are much more portable.

Comment: `mail()` uses the local MTA. Configuring that would be off-topic (even if you knew what it was). Also it's unclear if Yandex.Mail provides a SMTP gateway or just an API. So yes, `mail()` won't do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Thanks for the tip. I stopped on Swift Mailer, installed it with composer and tested with success. But when I try to use it in my project the error occurs ```SOAP: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')```. In the project dependencies are managed by PEAR package manager and I wonder how to use composer in a way that it wouldn't interfere with pear. Or how to include a swift mailer package via pear?

Comment: You can use both pear and composer in the same project. They won't interfere with each outer. Just do `composer install` in the same folder you have your `composer.json`-file on the server and you should be set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well, I did. Now I have files ```composer.json```, ```composer.phar```, ```composer.lock``` and folder ```vendor``` in the same directory in my project, but that error still wouldn't go.

Comment: Then the path is wrong.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah, path to php was explicitly mentioned in the source code, so I moved composer there and it did the trick. But now a certain class from source code not found. (I included it as such ```use Path\To\Class;```) It worked before...

Comment: actually, now all classes which I include via ```use``` keyword in this file not found